# Code works in Codepen, but not on my webhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a contrast change script, which sets cookies and gets them on page load.
This is working finde on Codepen with Console Log: "Contrast greenmonochrome loaded from cookie!",
but on the Webhost, the function dows not find any cookies and responds "No cookies found!" to Console Log.

I have checked the code several times, searched other related answers, but I cannot figure out, why this code is not working on my webhost.

Do you have any ideas or suggestions, please?
BR
Matthias

Codepen: https://codepen.io/matt-prime/pen/abzGEoY

```js
    // CONTRAST CHANGER
    $(document).ready(function(){
      console.log( "Event Listener ready!" );

      // CHECK FOR COOKIE
      var x = document.cookie;
      if(x=='blackwhite') {
        blackwhite();
        console.log( "Contrast blackwhite loaded from cookie!" );
      }

      else if(x=='whiteblack') {
        whiteblack();
        console.log( "Contrast whiteblack loaded from cookie!" );
      }

      else if(x=='yellowblue') {
        yellowblue();
        console.log( "Contrast yellowblue loaded from cookie!" );
      }

      else if(x=='blueyellow') {
        blueyellow();
        console.log( "Contrast blueyellow loaded from cookie!" );
      }

      else if(x=='bernsteinmonochrome') {
        bernsteinmonochrome();
        console.log( "Contrast bernsteinmonochrome loaded from cookie!" );
      }

      else if(x=='greenmonochrome') {
        greenmonochrome();
        console.log( "Contrast greenmonochrome loaded from cookie!" );
      }

      else if(x=='commodore64') {
        commodore64();
        console.log( "Contrast commodore64 loaded from cookie!" );
      }

      else {console.log( "No cookies found!" );
      }

      // CONTRAST DEFAULT
      $(".change-reset").click(function(){
     $("*").removeClass("contrast-black-white contrast-white-black contrast-yellow-blue contrast-blue-yellow contrast-monochrome-bernstein contrast-monochrome-gruen contrast-commodore64");
        // RESET COOKIE
        document.cookie=1
        console.log( "Contrast cookie reset!" );
      });

      // CONTRAST BLACK WHITE
      $(".changeBW").click(function(){blackwhite();});

      // CONTRAST WHITE BLACK
      $(".changeWB").click(function(){whiteblack();});

      // CONTRAST YELLOW BLUE
      $(".changeYB").click(function(){yellowblue();});

      // CONTRAST BLUE YELLOW
      $(".changeBY").click(function(){blueyellow()});

      // KONTRAST BERNSTEIN MONOCHROM
      $(".changeBM").click(function(){bernsteinmonochrome()});

      // CONTRAST GREEN MONOCHROM
      $(".changeGM").click(function(){greenmonochrome()});

      // CONTRAST COMMODORE 64
      $(".changeC64").click(function(){commodore64()});

    // CONTRAST LAYOUT CSS CLASSES
    function blackwhite(){
      $("*").removeClass("contrast-black-white contrast-white-black contrast-yellow-blue contrast-blue-yellow contrast-monochrome-bernstein contrast-monochrome-gruen contrast-commodore64");
      $("*").addClass("contrast-black-white");
      $("i.icon.fas.fa-adjust.contrast-black-white").removeClass("contrast-black-white");
      $("span.btn-label.contrast-black-white").removeClass("contrast-black-white");
      document.cookie = 'blackwhite';
      console.log( "Contrast cookie blackwhite set!" );
    }

    function whiteblack(){
      $("*").removeClass("contrast-black-white contrast-white-black contrast-yellow-blue contrast-blue-yellow contrast-monochrome-bernstein contrast-monochrome-gruen contrast-commodore64");
      $("*").addClass("contrast-white-black");
      $("i.icon.fas.fa-adjust.contrast-white-black").removeClass("contrast-white-black");
      $("span.btn-label.contrast-white-black").removeClass("contrast-white-black");
      document.cookie = 'whiteblack';
      console.log( "Contrast cookie whiteblack set!" );
    }

    function yellowblue(){
      $("*").removeClass("contrast-black-white contrast-white-black contrast-yellow-blue contrast-blue-yellow contrast-monochrome-bernstein contrast-monochrome-gruen contrast-commodore64");
      $("*").addClass("contrast-yellow-blue");
      $("i.icon.fas.fa-adjust.contrast-yellow-blue").removeClass("contrast-yellow-blue");
      $("span.btn-label.contrast-yellow-blue").removeClass("contrast-yellow-blue");
      document.cookie = 'yellowblue';
      console.log( "Contrast cookie yellowblue set!" );
    }

    function blueyellow(){
       $("*").removeClass("contrast-black-white contrast-white-black contrast-yellow-blue contrast-blue-yellow contrast-monochrome-bernstein contrast-monochrome-gruen contrast-commodore64");
      $("*").addClass("contrast-blue-yellow");
      $("i.icon.fas.fa-adjust.contrast-blue-yellow").removeClass("contrast-blue-yellow");
      $("span.btn-label.contrast-blue-yellow").removeClass("contrast-blue-yellow");
      document.cookie = 'blueyellow';
      console.log( "Contrast cookie blueyellow set!" );
    }


  })
```

Comment: Can you pare this down to the actual cookie code? Most of this doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: I have copied code from Codepen to Stackoverflow 1:1 to avoid mistakes.
All the cookie issues happen in the JS snippet.

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Code should be reduced to the minimum necessary to reproduce. Unrelated, but there's just a *huge* amount of duplication in this code.

Comment: console.log(document.cookie)

Comment: @DaveNewton I have reduced the snippets now.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work for codepen either for me. What I think has happened is the following

[image: Codepen Result]

1. At some point you run code in codepen that created the cookie with the value you wanted
2. The cookies persist in the domain they run, especially when the don't have expiration date in them
3. Now when you run the page in codepen you get a result.

Clear the cookies in codepen and see that you'll have the same result. That makes sense.

You must set the cookie somewhere (and there is no code that you do that). Then when the page loads, it checks for the value.

You could return a non-Http cookie from the server side that you set the value of the cookie. The implementation depends on the backend technology. You can inject a cookie on the web server too.

The only places you set the cookie, is when the cookie is already set and you re-set it in the functions.

Comment: The cookie is set only, when a special contrast is chosen. I have deleted codepen cookies and even tried another browser in privacy mode. As soon as I select a contrast, the appropriate cookie is (re-)set within codepen.
If I do not select a contrast, no cookie will be set, that's fine.

But I will have a look into the document.cookie reference, as cookies without duration or expiry date are handled as session cookies. This could be the reason of the problem